# Return ID of saved Active Storage object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Hi I am trying to upload an attachment using Active Storage and then return it's database ID, so I can use for referencing to download later.

This is the attach code i have:

```
attachment = @message.images.attach(params[:image])
```

This attaches the image, however it returns a boolean.

Is there a way I can get saved ID of the Active Storage object so I can use it?

Comment: what does the attach method do? like an update? Cause that's the function updating it and you can pull the id after it updates.

Comment: Na the attach method saves the attachment as the ActiveStorage object.   It simply returns a boolean, and no way to use it afterwards.   I have raised issue in github https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39352